# Stored procedure truncates a variable using the CONCAT function immediately after a parameter is included in the CONCAT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass a parameter [e.g. `@X nvarchar(MAX)`] into a variable [e.g. `@message nvarchar(MAX)`] inside a stored procedure. The variable is using `CONCAT` to combine string values and variables, and it ultimately becomes both the body of an email that is sent from SQL Server and the value of a column in a table. For some reason, when I set the variable, the `CONCAT` ends immediately after the first parameter is passed to it.

One extra detail is that it works fine when I run the stored procedure manually. In this particular case, this issue only appears when the stored procedure is called from an external application.

I have tried the following options without success:

- Setting the variable without `CONCAT` using triple single quotes
- Passing the parameter to a separate variable prior to the @message variable
- Setting the parameter to allow for OUTPUT to the original application (even though the original application does not need the OUTPUT)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TEST] 
    (@param NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @email NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @email = 'test@test.com'

    SET @message = CONCAT ('Some text.',CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        ,'Value of param: ', @param, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
        ,'Some more text.');

    INSERT INTO [database].[dbo].[table] ([Message], [Param])
    VALUES (@message, @param);

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @recipients = @email,
            @body = @message,
            @subject = 'SUBJECT OF EMAIL',
            @profile_name = 'profile_name';
```

The email is sent fine, and the message is stored to [table], but in both cases, the `@message` variable ends right after the `@param` is passed to it.

For example, if the value of `@param` was "paramTest", `@message` would look like this:

```
Some text.
Value of param: paramTest
```

Also, the param is stored fine to [table], so I know that the parameter has a valid value.

Is there a way to capture and see the exact data that is being passed from the external application to the stored procedure? I have been wondering if it is including some sort of special character(s) at the end of the data when it assigns the parameter.

Comment: My first thought is that the @param value ends with a NULL (or CHAR(0)) causing SQL to think that is the end of the string.

Comment: Well if you run the sproc manually and run ok then the problem is how are you calling the sproc from the app. What are you using?

Comment: "Is there a way to capture and see the exact data that is being passed from the external application to the stored procedure?"   Yes, it's called SQL Profiler.   And I recommend that you try it.

Comment: The app is called deviceWise, and it's pulling the parameter from a a tag on a PLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking at the Message as a sequence of bytes. e.g.:

```
select *, cast([Message] as varbinary(max)) as DataAsBytes 
from [database].[dbo].[table]
```

This allows you to see the byte representation of all characters.

Example:

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'b' + CHAR(0); 
DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @message = CONCAT ('a', @param, 'c');
select  @message as RawMessage, CAST(@message as varbinary(max)) as MessageAsBytes, LEN(@message) as RawMessageLength, DATALENGTH(CAST(@message as varbinary(max))) as NumBytes
```

When run in SSMS, shows RawMessage as: ab, so the CHAR(0) character has caused SSMS to not display the following 'c'. 
MessageAsBytes is shown as: 0x6100620000006300
where: 'a' = 6100, 'b' = 6200, CHAR(0)  = 0000, 'c' = 6300. 
So you can "see" the CHAR(0) character.

Background info on unicode encoding:

https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses

Comment: I'll check to see if there is a CHAR(0) tomorrow. Thanks for the great suggestion!

Comment: I finally was able to check the data today, and the parameters are being passed with CHAR(0) at the end. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Check what is passed as a parameter value.

Demo

```
DECLARE @param NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'abc msg' + CHAR(0); -- all the rest is lost

DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @message = CONCAT ('Some text.',CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    ,'Value of param: ', @param, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    ,'Some more text.');

select @message;
```

Returns

```
Some text.
Value of param: abc msg
```

Comment: I've seen that `A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.`. In this case it makes sense, as there is a CHAR(0) in the middle, which is supposed to mean NULL, then meaning the end of the string. it may have another CHAR(0) in the end, but as said, it's terminated in the first null character, not the last

Comment: I finally was able to check the data today, and the parameters are being passed with CHAR(0) at the end. Thanks for your help!